# native regular expression with replace

Tags: regex

Can you please help with the regular expression for the below problem pattern. I am unable to perform replace operation using regex.

Source string:

```
/search/zip-12345/district-324
```

Replacement expression would be `/search.html?$1`

The following regex `/search/((?:"[^"]*"|[^:,])*)` provides output as

```
/search.html?zip-12345/district-324
```

But the expected output is

```
/search.html?zip=12345&district=324
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: This is for AEM etc map configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
(\/search)\/([^\/-]+)-([^\/]+)\/([^-]+)-(.*)
```

With substitution:

```
$1.html?$2=$3&$4=$5
```

https://regex101.com/r/m5lkw6/4

Comment: @Karan It is always nice to either upvote or accept the answer that helped you, or both.